# Resize SDL window without resizing the content

Tags: c, sdl

I'm trying to resize my SDL window. I want to resize it like a viewport rather than resizing all the contents inside.

To illustrate what I mean:

[This is my original window before resizing, sized 400x400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba5ex.png)

[This is the window after resizing down to 200x200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLka3.png)

The texture I'm drawing in the window got scaled down to fit the new window dimensions. I don't want this. I need the texture to keep the same dimensions it had at the beginning and just draw the part of the texture that's visible within the new window size, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKwfW.png) (the red area shows the original window surface, the clear area shows the resized window surface I want)

This is the function I'm using to tro to accomplish this:

```
void update_window_size(SDL_Window* window, int w, int h)
{
    SDL_SetWindowSize(window, w, h);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the SDL library other than `SDL_SetWindowSize` to help me accomplish this. I'm hoping I can do this without calling upon OpenGL since none of my other code needs to. But I also tried calling `glViewport` without success.

Comment: *"do this without calling upon OpenGL since none of my other code needs to"* Do you use a `SDL_Renderer`, or do you draw stuff with OpenGL?

Comment: I use an `SDL_Renderer`. I draw everything on the screen using `SDL_RenderCopy`

Comment: Well that question pointed me in the right direction... it works as intended if I just call `SDL_RenderSetScale(renderer, 1.0, 1.0)` right after `SDL_SetWindowSize`. It seems like `SDL_SetWindowSize` changed the renderer scale internally?

Comment: If you use the renderer, why do you even touch OpenGL? (e.g. `glViewport(0, 0, w, h);`) You shouldn't, as the renderer doesn't necessarily use OpenGL under the hood.